# how to enable zip64 while creating grails war?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I am running grails war.

error: 
Error WAR packaging error: archive contains more than 65535 entries.

How to enable zip64 in grails?

Answer (score 6):

In your `build.gradle`

```
war {
    zip64 = true
}
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html

Comment: build.gradle in available after grails 3.x. 
I am using grails-2.5.4, it has BuildConfig.groovy.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't see the tag. I doubt that feature is available in 2.x

Comment: Is that any solution found for grails 2.5?